# Why open sets in $\mathbf R^k$ is Polish?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading van der Vaart and Wellner . The footnote $\dagger$ on p.17 says that $(0,1)$ is Polish. But seems to me that $(0,1)$ is not complete. Do I miss something here?

Comment: The key thing that this shows is that completeness is a *metric* property, not a *topological* one.

Answer (score 3):

$(0,1)$ is *topologically* complete (also referred to as *completely metrizable*): it’s homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and therefore has a complete metric that generates its topology.

Comment: Note that, for the same reason, $\mathbb R$ admits a metric (giving the same topology) under which it is not complete. This is why Polish spaces are asked to be completely metrizable (rather than being directly given with a complete metric).

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! Could you tell me any texts that I can look up for more details?

Comment: @Pittance: Texts on descriptive set theory are the natural place to look; one by Y. Moschovakis is freely available [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/books.htm), and David Marker has a set of lecture notes available [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! This is very helpful, especially the second notes. There I found a conclusion (Lemma 1.30) saying that any open subsets of Polish space is Polish. The proof is done by constructing a metric on the open subset so that this set is complete under this (potentially) new metric. So I was wondering where can I find a proof using your homeomorphism arguments? Feel free to ignore this question if it is meaningless to you. Once again, thank you!

Comment: @Pittance: Here we were lucky, because $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to a well-known complete metric space, but in general that won’t happen, and you actually have to construct an equivalent complete metric from scratch, as Marker does. You’re welcome!